# How to detect "would like to use your current location" choose action?

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, cllocationmanager

As we know `CLLocationManager` can be used to get the current location with the permission of the alert: "MyAppName" Would Like to Use Your Current Location" | "Don't Allow" | "Allow". How could we detect the choose action after the user choose "Don't Allow" or "Allow"? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:   (CLAuthorizationStatus)status {

    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        // Don't Allow
    }
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        //Allow
    }
}
```

Implement `CLLocationManagerDelegate` and use this delegate method

Comment: The comments seem backwards to me